# Automating SELinux user mappings for SSSD AD users without an IdM solution

Tags: centos, rhel, pam, selinux, sssd

I have several RHEL7 and CentOS7 based systems that are tied into a Windows Server 2019 Active Directory using realms/SSSD.

Currently, AD users adopt the unconfined_u SELinux user mapping by default. I can manually create a confined user mapping for each user with the semanage command, however this is not practical.

I want to be able to automate the SELinux user mapping for my Active Directory users, without having to setup and maintain an intermediary IdM solution. Is this possible with just native SSSD configuration or PAM libraries?

Thanks for any advice provided!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `__default__` SELinux user mapping may fit your use case.

This is covered in `man 8 semanage-login`, where they set `__default__` to `guest_u`:

```
Modify the default user on the system to the guest_u user
# semanage login -m -s guest_u __default__
```